# Recording GPS position

Tags: quadcopter, gps

I build 3d models using Agisoft and need to record the position of the Ground Control Points as accurately as possible, latitude , longitude and altitude. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mark Watson, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate position is probably calculated by using a sensor-fusion algorithm.

As sensors you can use:

- GPS for absolute (but relatively inprecise position)
- Distance sensors (either via triangulation with multiple ground stations or via a SLAM algorithm)
- Odometric data from your quadrocopter (motor power)
- Acceleration (lot's of drift over time but precise for a short time)

This sensor data can be fused used something like a Kalman-Filter.